# SQL SELECT TOP <dynamic> BASED ON CATEGORY/PERCENTAGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

Here is the sample data that I have:

[image]

Out of the 11 rows, I need to SELECT TOP 60% of the rows from CAT-1, 30% from CAT-2 AND 10% from CAT-3. Can someone please help me with building a SQL? The target is a SQL 2014 DB.

Comment: How about a union?

Comment: Pleaese do not poste your data as picture. That makes it really hard to set up a test scenario!

Comment: If the data you posted is your real table there is a huge design flaw: You must create a "Category" Table and use it via Foreign Key with your customers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add this as a new answer, because my first answer is something completely different. User "Les H" brought me to this:

```
--Credits to @Les H
SELECT *
INTO #Test
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'A', 'CAT-1', 60),
(2, 'B', 'CAT-1', 60),
(3, 'C', 'CAT-1', 60),
(4, 'D', 'CAT-1', 60),
(5, 'E', 'CAT-1', 60),
(6, 'F', 'CAT-2', 30),
(7, 'G', 'CAT-2', 30),
(8, 'H', 'CAT-2', 30),
(9, 'I', 'CAT-3', 10),
(10, 'J', 'CAT-3', 10),
(11, 'K', 'CAT-1', 60)
) A (RowID, Customer, Category, Percentage)


 SELECT Percentages.*
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Category,Percentage FROM #Test) AS c
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (c.Percentage) PERCENT * FROM #Test WHERE #Test.Category=c.Category ORDER BY #Test.RowID) AS Percentages;

 DROP TABLE #Test;
```

The result:

```
1   A   CAT-1   60
2   B   CAT-1   60
3   C   CAT-1   60
4   D   CAT-1   60
6   F   CAT-2   30
9   I   CAT-3   10
```

Comment: Nice! I chased this down a rabbit hole earlier today, so simple in the end

Comment: @Shnugo, This is exactly what I need. Thanks for your time. See we do not need SQL 2022 magic edition :)

Comment: @Shnugo, Marked as answer. I am not that frequent here, so didn't know that part. I will take care of marking answers moving forward. Have a good one! Also, this is not the exact table/data. I had different table/data which is properly normalized.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested the query but you should be able to use `UNION ALL`

```
  SELECT TOP(60) PERCENT *
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE Category = 'CAT-1'
UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP(30) PERCENT *
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE Category = 'CAT-2'
UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP(10) PERCENT *
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE Category = 'CAT-3'
```

Obviously you will have to define some `ORDER BY` criteria or the top 60% will be an arbitrary result.

Comment: The categories are going to be dynamic again. So I am afraid if I can hard code the categories and its %

Comment: @user2980765, If everything is dynamic you'd need the brand new SQL Server 2022 magic edition :-) Honestly: How should a poor little query know  what you need?

Comment: @Shnugo, Good joke and I will take time off tomorrow to laugh at it. I am a very basic sql developer and I was wondering if there is way that I am missing. At present, I am doing a CURSOR with those dynamic categories and then selecting the data. I hope there is nothing wrong in checking it out.

Comment: @user2980765, hang on some minutes, I'll provide a suggestion with dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can do

```
DECLARE @N INT = 20
SELECT TOP (@n) PERCENT * FROM BLAH
```

I couldn't grok a way of setting `@N` for each group in your data (`CROSS APPLY` anyone?).

So here's a solution using two CTEs. It's probably far from optimal :)

### Test Data

```
SELECT *
INTO #Test
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'A', 'CAT-1', 60),
(2, 'B', 'CAT-1', 60),
(3, 'C', 'CAT-1', 60),
(4, 'D', 'CAT-1', 60),
(5, 'E', 'CAT-1', 60),
(6, 'F', 'CAT-2', 30),
(7, 'G', 'CAT-2', 30),
(8, 'H', 'CAT-2', 30),
(9, 'I', 'CAT-3', 10),
(10, 'J', 'CAT-3', 10),
(11, 'K', 'CAT-1', 60)
) A (RowID, Customer, Category, Percentage)
```

### Solution

Here I'm ranking and counting each group in the first CTE then setting the 'percentage bracket range' in the second CTE (this is to catch for example a top 10% query that only has two rows where the brackets would be 50% and 100%).

```
;WITH Ranked AS (
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY RowId)  * 100 RANK,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ) COUNT
    FROM #Test),
Grouped AS (
    SELECT *, 
    COALESCE(LAG(RANK) OVER (PARTITION BY Category order BY Rank) / COUNT, 0) BracketStart,
    RANK / COUNT BracketEnd
    FROM Ranked
)
SELECT 
    G.RowID
    ,G.Customer
    ,G.Category
FROM Grouped G
WHERE G.BracketEnd <= G.Percentage OR G.Percentage BETWEEN G.BracketStart AND G.BracketEnd
ORDER BY G.Category

RowID       Customer Category
----------- -------- --------
1           A        CAT-1
2           B        CAT-1
3           C        CAT-1
4           D        CAT-1
6           F        CAT-2
9           I        CAT-3
```

Comment: Hi, your answer brought me to a new approach. Upvote from my side for your "CROSS APPLY anyone". I copied your TestData-section, hope you don't mind...

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach with dynamic SQL. First I create separate tables for customers and categories. Then a SQL command is generated. Check it out:

```
CREATE TABLE #Cat(CatID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,Category VARCHAR(100),Percentage INT);
INSERT INTO #Cat(Category,Percentage) VALUES('CAT-1',60),('CAT-2',30),('CAT-3',10);

CREATE TABLE #Cust(CustID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                  ,Customer VARCHAR(100)
                  ,CatID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #Cat(CatID));
INSERT INTO #Cust(Customer,CatID) VALUES
 ('A',1),('B',1),('C',1),('D',1),('E',1),('F',2),('G',2),('H',2),('I',3),('J',3),('K',1);

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 'UNION ALL SELECT TOP(' +  CAST(c.Percentage AS VARCHAR(10)) + ') PERCENT * FROM #Cust WHERE CatID=' + CAST(c.CatID AS  VARCHAR(10)) + ' '
            FROM #Cat AS c
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,10,''
    )
);


SET @cmd='SELECT tbl.CustID,tbl.Customer,tbl.CatID,c.Category,c.Percentage FROM(' +  @cmd + ') AS tbl INNER JOIN #Cat AS c ON c.CatID=tbl.CatID';

--This is the generated query
SELECT @cmd;

--And this is its execution
EXEC (@cmd);

DROP TABLE #Cust;
DROP TABLE #Cat;
```

The result:

```
1   A   1   CAT-1   60
2   B   1   CAT-1   60
3   C   1   CAT-1   60
4   D   1   CAT-1   60
6   F   2   CAT-2   30
9   I   3   CAT-3   10
```